# getdate() through fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to insert a record through fluent, where a column need to have the value of getdate() sql function. How to do this in a single fluent save function?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using a default value at the database level?  Are you okay with setting the date on the client side before saving?  What have you already tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [IPreInsertEventListener](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx) implementation. They can be registered in Fluent NHibernate like this:

```
// Set event listeners for maintaining audit fields
var preInsertListeners = new IPreInsertEventListener[] {new AuditEventListener()};
var preUpdateListeners = new IPreUpdateEventListener[] {new AuditEventListener()};
fluentConfig.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.EventListeners.PreInsertEventListeners = preInsertListeners);
fluentConfig.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.EventListeners.PreUpdateEventListeners = preUpdateListeners);
```